# Mongoengine String Field in List field make unique

Tags: mongoengine

I use mongoengine and flask-restplus for API Server.

My model is here.

```
from datetime import datetime
from mongoengine import *
from config import DB_NAME

connect(DB_NAME)

class Board(Document):
    d = datetime.now()
    date = "{}-{}-{}".format(d.year, d.month, d.day)

    no = SequenceField()
    title = StringField(required=True)
    body = StringField(required=True)
    tags = ListField(StringField(unique=True))
    password = StringField(required=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=date)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(default=date)
```

I defined `tags = ListField(StringField(unique=True))`.

Because article can't got duplicated tag.

Insert tag code is here.

```
tag = ~some user input here~
article = Board.objects.get(no=article_no)
article.tags.append(tag)
article.save()
```

But when I insert the duplicated data, it stored data twice.

I want to `tags` has distinct data.

Why `unique=True` doesn't work?

Is there any solution about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [explanation](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/440) why does it not work. As a workaround you could use `$addToSet` operator provided by Mongo. It is also implemented in `Mongoengine`([docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#atomic-updates)) and an example usage would look like this

```
Board.objects(no=article_no).update_one(add_to_set__tags=tag)
```

where tag can be string or list of strings